# Kivy/buildozer error al crear mi apk

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

Tengo un inconveniente al intentar crear un apk a partir de mi archivo .py creado con el framework kivy el error y los comandos que use son los siguientes

```
 wonder@wonder-M720SR:~/Kivy-Calculator$ buildozer android debug
```

deploy run

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/wonder/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/wonder/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/wonder/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/wonder/Kivy-Calculator/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

ejecutando el comando que genero el problema recibo este resultado:

```
wonder@wonder-M720SR:~/Kivy-Calculator$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/wonder/Kivy-Calculator/.buildozer/android/platform/build
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found possible SDK dirs in buildozer dir: android-sdk-20
[INFO]:    Will attempt to use SDK at /home/wonder/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
[WARNING]: This SDK lookup is intended for debug only, if you use python-for-android much you should probably maintain your own SDK download.
[INFO]:    Android API target was not set manually, using the default of 15
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[WARNING]: Requested API target 15 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.
[WARNING]: Exiting.
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: Wonderly, aprovecho para invitarte a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**En este caso es importante instalar el SDK que se indica como target**, esto para que genere el .apk, si no defines un target se configura por default el API 15

> Android API target was not set manually, using the default of 15
>   [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19) [WARNING]: Requested API
>   target 15 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.

Pero el API 15 no esta instalado, es necesario instalarlo o como otra opción define como target el 19 que es el que tienes actualmente instalado.

Edita tu archivo `buildozer.spec` y agrega la versión del SDK a usar (debe estar instalado), por ejemplo si es 19:

```
# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21
android.sdk = 19
```

Comment: no compilo el apk por que aparecio otro error pero me fue util !!! gracias